# Printing HTTP header on terminal

Tags: python, http, networking, tcp, pcap

I am currently creating a packet sniffer using python and pcap. After following this code:
https://www.binarytides.com/code-a-packet-sniffer-in-python-with-pcapy-extension/

I am able to parse IP and TCP header to get the values such as source address, port number, etc.
I only need HTTP request/response so I filtered out to only keep the ones that have the port number 80.

However, I am really confused on how to print out the actual values of HTTP header. Where and how am I supposed to get the image below to appear on my MacOS terminal?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your HTTP data stored? What format? Is it just block of bytes with whole response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your HTTP response packet data in `http_response_data` variable as python `bytes` type you can get response headers just in one line:

```
headers_text = http_response_data.partition(b'\r\n\r\n')[0].decode('utf-8')
print(headers_text)
```

Also you might need to use `'cp852'` instead of `'utf-8'` if HTTP headers are not UTF-8 encoded.

This takes into account the fact that HTTP headers are separated from HTTP content body by two newlines (all header lines are separated just by one newline).

Next is small example of usage solution above by receiving HTTP bytes response from TCP port 80 of Google's server using standard `socket` library.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64074158#main.py)

```
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(('google.com', 80))
s.send(b'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n')
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
http_response_data = s.recv(8192) # TCP response stored as bytes
s.close()
headers_text = http_response_data.partition(b'\r\n\r\n')[0].decode('utf-8')
print(headers_text)
```

**PS**:

1. Your headers might be not UTF-8 encoded then instead of `.decode('utf-8')` try other encoding/code-page like this `.decode('cp852')`.
2. `headers_text` will contain also status line like `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` if you don't need it (if important to have only `key: value` lines) you can use next code instead:

```
headers_text = http_response_data.partition(b'\r\n\r\n')[0].partition(b'\r\n')[2].decode('utf-8')
print(headers_text)
```

3. According to [your tutorial](https://www.binarytides.com/code-a-packet-sniffer-in-python-with-pcapy-extension/) TCP data as bytes type is available at the end of body of `if protocol == 6 :` block as `data` variable, use it as `http_response_data` in my solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tried your Google example above and it outputs exactly what I'm looking for. However, when I use your solution by replacing http_response_data with data I get the following error message: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte -- Do you know what might be happening? Thanks so much!

Comment: Here is what I have at the end of if protocol == 6: body
data = packet[h_size:]
headers_text = data.partition(b'\r\n\r\n')[0].partition(b'\r\n')[2].decode('utf-8')
print(headers_text)

Comment: @Bamdfw1 Try first solution, `headers_text = data.partition(b'\r\n\r\n')[0].decode('utf-8')`, probably in your case there are no headers at all, just status line. If it doesn't work try printing first bytes to console to see how they look like `print(data[:2048])`. If they are not UTF encoded then instead of utf-8 try using `.decode('cp866')`.

Comment: I've realized that when I print type(data) on my solution, it actually tells me that it is a string instead of bytes. When I run print(data) however I get results that I cannot interpret. Is there a way to fix this??

Comment: @Bamdfw1 It is of type `str` because you're using Python 2 not 3. Python 2 has only str type not bytes, but still you  should be able to use my code. Just print first bytes `print(data[:2048])` to see what is contained there.

Comment: @Bamdfw1 Probably `cp852` is even better than `cp866` as first is latin second is russian.